# How to automatically fill address inputs in checkout (Stripe)

Tags: stripe-payments

I would like to fill automatically the address inputs in the Stripe checkout so the users won't type it two times,
I created a customer with an shipping address and I used the customer ID into Checkout Session, but address inputs are still empty, except the email

```
$customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(
        [
            'email' => $request->email,
            'shipping' =>
                [
                    'address' => [
                        'city' => $request->city,
                        'country' => $var,
                        'line1' => $request->address,
                        'postal_code' => $request->postal_code
                    ],
                    'name' => 'foo bar'
                ]
        ]
    );
```

Thank you.

Comment: It seems like there is a shipping key in Checkout Object I will test it.

Comment: I meant Session Object, but server answered with eceived unknown parameter: shipping. Did you mean shipping_rates? {"userId":1,"exception":"[object] (Stripe\\Exception\\InvalidRequestException(code: 0): Received unknown parameter: shipping. Did you mean shipping_rates? Cannot modify when creating a Session